# React: Integration of Axios Instance, allowing Token Refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, amazon-cognito

The structure of my React app is as follows:

```
const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));root.render(
<Provider store={store}>
     <BrowserRouter>
         <AuthProvider>
             <Routes />
         </AuthProvider>
     </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

- I have a Redux store servicing the entire app (using Thunks to communicate
  with server via API requests and update the store)
- I then have an AuthProvider context to handle the authentications functions (using the AWS Cognito library)

I now want to abstract all API requests to an Axios instance, using interceptors to handle token refresh. Something like this:

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        accept: 'application/json'
    }
});

apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async (error) => {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        if (error.response.status === 403 && !originalRequest.retry) {
            originalRequest.retry = true;
            // Will need to do a refresh
            const access_token = await refreshToken();
            return apiClient(originalRequest);
        }
        throw error;
    }
);

export default apiClient;
```

Problem: How do I implement the `refreshToken()` call as it is already part of my `useAuth()` hook?

I can't access the `useAuth()` hook from the Axios instance as it is not a React Functional component, and I can't make it into an Axios context (like `useAxios()`) as it will need to be the parent of the the Redux store (which means that, again, it cant access the `useAuth()` hook.

I am sure this is not an uncommon issue, and one that must have an elegant solution – however I can’t seem to find one.

Any suggestion gratefully received

Comment: Can you provide the code for `refreshToken()`?

Comment: @SatejBidvai As part of the AWS Cognito library you can call `refreshSession()` on the current Cognito user, else `getSession()` will return a valid, refreshed token.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have a "work-around" as opposed to a solution, but would still apprciate any suggestion on a standard way to achieve this.

My solution was to initialize the axios instance's interceptors from within my   AuthProvider[image]

within my AuthProvider I have access to the the AWS Cognito function `refreshSession()` as well as `.getIdToken().getJwtToken()` for the immediate retry.

Works - not sure it is the most elegant solution.